# PostgreSQL - Any downside to using JSONB as a single function argument

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

So I have a PG function `create_order` (language is PL/PGSQL) which accepts a quite a few arguments.
I have noticed that every time I modify argument name, its type, or if I add a new argument, I have to drop the function (`CREATE OR REPLACE` does not work)

So I have been thinking what if I just accept one single argument of type `jsonb` and call it day...So the signature would look like `create_order(args jsonb)`

My questions are

1. is this considered bad practice in PG "world" (affects performance or some other aspect) or bad practice from a programming standpoint
2. if #1 is bad approach, would it better to create custom composite type and use it as an argument to a function?

Comment: What is wrong about re-creating the function if you change its signature? You do have to update the calls to it anyways, don't you?

Comment: I would not use first because you would have the downside of converting the parameter types. The second I have already used in my time and given yours requirements (somewhat constant changes) I think that it is a better approach, I would go for it. You would keep a better maintainability to your procedure even in code where you use it would not be needed to change every time (except the first, obviously). I didn't add it as an answer because this is an opinion, I just didn't vote to close as it because it is a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a big problem with a `jsonb` function parameter, except maybe that individual parameters make it more obvious what the input values are. But that's nothing that can't be fixed with documentation.

On the other hand, I also see no problem with dropping and recreating functions when the signature changes. It may serve as a reminder that calling sites need to be updated.

I'd say that you should go with the approach that fits you and the problem at hand best – it does not matter from the PostgreSQL point of view.

Comment: dropping and recreating is not an issue for me either but it gets hairy when function is used in other functions. Then you have to cascade drop and recreate all of them (unless I missed something ?)

Comment: There are no dependencies between functions like for example between views and tables, so you can just drop and recreate a function that is called in another function. But if the signature changes, you will have to change the calling function too to avoid a runtime error when the function is called. But you have to modify the calling function anyway, right?